# ElasticSearch NEST ObjectInitializer syntax to fluent syntax translation not working

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Given this ObjectInitializer NEST query

```
var mustClauses = new List<QueryContainer>
{
    new QueryStringQuery
    {
        Query = queryFilter.Query,
        Lenient = true
    },
    new MatchQuery
    {
        Field = new Field("status"),
        Query = queryFilter.Status,
        Lenient = true,
        Operator = Operator.And
    },
    new DateRangeQuery
    {
        Field = new Field("timeSent"),
        LessThanOrEqualTo = now,
        GreaterThanOrEqualTo = GetDateTimeFor(queryFilter.TimeCriteria, now)
    }
};
return client.SearchAsync<Ingestion.Entities.ElasticSearch.MessageData>(sd => sd.Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(mustClauses.ToArray())))
   .Sort(x => x.Descending(b => b.TimeSent))
   .From(from)
   .Size(pageSize));
```

which works, and outputs the following query to my Visual Studio Output window:

```
{"from":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"status":{"lenient":true,"operator":"and","query":"Success"}}},{"range":{"timeSent":{"gte":"2021-12-14T03:39:26.5126419Z","lte":"2021-12-21T03:39:26.5126419Z"}}}]}},"size":20,"sort":[{"timeSent":{"order":"desc"}}]}
```

I am trying to convert it to fluent query syntax like this:

```
return client.SearchAsync<Ingestion.Entities.ElasticSearch.MessageData>(sd => sd.Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(
    mu => mu
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .Query(queryFilter.Query)
            .Lenient(true)),

    mu =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryFilter.Status))
            return null;

        return mu
            .Match(ma => ma.Field(f => f.Status == queryFilter.Status)
            .Lenient(true)
            .Operator(Operator.And));
        },

        mu =>
        {
            if (queryFilter.TimeCriteria == TimeCriteria.All)
                return null;

            return mu.DateRange(dr => dr
                .Field(f => f.TimeSent)
                .LessThanOrEquals(now)
                .GreaterThanOrEquals(GetDateTimeFor(queryFilter.TimeCriteria, now)));
        })))
    .Sort(x => x.Descending(b => b.TimeSent))
    .From(from)
    .Size(pageSize));
```

and it's not working. When I run this query, the Match query on that Status field does not appear in the NEST output.

Any guidance/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The status lambda expression should be

```cs
    mu =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryFilter.Status))
            return null;

        return mu
            .Match(ma => ma.Field(f => f.Status)
            .Query(queryFilter.Status)
            .Lenient(true)
            .Operator(Operator.And));
    },
```